# jpegcam with codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

`<script language="JavaScript">
        webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
        webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
        webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
</script>`

i try jpegcam in my website (i use codeigniter).
and i cant load my webcam.swf or webcam.php or test.php.
how can i reach php in javascript loke this in codeigniter?

when i refresh my website theres nothing to do there, but when i try the jpegcam (without codeigniter) its works well.  sorry for my silly question, im new with codeigniter,

```
<table><tr><td valign=top>
<h1>JPEGCam Test Page</h1>

<!-- First, include the JPEGCam JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
    webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
    webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
</script>

<!-- Next, write the movie to the page at 320x240 -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>

<!-- Some buttons for controlling things -->
<br/><form>
    <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="webcam.snap()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle the server response (see test.php) -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

    function my_completion_handler(msg) {
        // extract URL out of PHP output
        if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
            var image_url = RegExp.$1;
            // show JPEG image in page
            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = 
                '<h1>Upload Successful!</h1>' + 
                '<img src="'+image_url+'">';
        }
        else alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
    }
</script>

</td><td width=50>&nbsp;</td><td valign=top>
    <div id="upload_results"></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

please help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the base_url function of the URL Helper (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to load your assets file and controller.

For example:

```
echo base_url("path/to/webcam.swf");
echo base_url("path/to/webcamuploadhandler/controller");
```

I think you also need to set the `set_shutter_sound` to load the appropriate .mp3 file, something like this in your view file:

```
webcam.set_shutter_sound(true, "<?php echo base_url("path/to/shutter.mp3"); ?>");
```

Furthermore, since you use a framework, I guess you have to set response Content-type of the `webcamuploadhandler/controller` as `"text/plain"`. There is an issue I experienced lately: http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/issues/detail?id=15